# DialogFragment display a list of icons with paging

Tags: android, android-pageradapter

In my app, users can send an icon/gift to other users. I want to show a DialogFragment popup that includes paging of available icons.

For example, I have a total of 15 icons to display. I want to show 6 icons per page, which means i should have 3 "pages" to swipe through horizontally.

[image: Similar pager]

I tried using a FragmentPagerAdapter and RecyclerView with GridLayout for the icons. But it's not really working like i want it.

How can this be implemented using a PagerAdapter without any fragments?

Comment: So what's the problem with your solution using `FragmentPagerAdapter` and `RecyclierView` inside?

Answer (score 4):

If you dont want to use fragments then try with a normal activity with a dialog theme. eg; `<activity android:name="your_activity_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />`

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a DialogFragment with ViewPager and Pager Indicator in it (as per your design).
2. Add a PagerAdapter for the ViewPager.
3. Create a layout and add the RecyclerView in it.
4. Now use that layout created in 3rd Step in PagerAdapter and inside PagerAdapter, set Adapter for recyclerview with GridLayoutManager and Horizontal Orientation and show the 6 items from your list.

Comment: If you made this before, can you please share code samples?

Answer (score 0):

You can use three pages each containing a `RecyclerView`, each page is a custom view instead of a fragment.
But you still have to use the `ViewPager` to navigate through the pages